# Duplicate rows in CSV file n times based on value of column

Tags: python

I have a CSV file that has the following data structure -
[image]

I want to repeat duplicate the rows the number of times the value of row 'repeat' is.
So, for the Frame# 4- I want to repeat the whole row 2 times.

Input -

```
Frame#  Yaw Pitch   Roll    KeyCode EyeX    EyeY    Repeat
1   13.116  -13.601 -16.871 -   480.86  175.24  1
2   13.553  -14.146 -17.872 -   469.12  161.7   1
3   13.885  -14.621 -18.694 -   465.38  161.75  1
4   13.425  -14.674 -18.614 -   465.67  154.52  2
5   13.153  -14.539 -18.069 -   457.33  136.78  3
```

Output -

```
Frame#  Yaw Pitch   Roll    KeyCode EyeX    EyeY    Repeat
1   13.116  -13.601 -16.871 -   480.86  175.24  1
2   13.553  -14.146 -17.872 -   469.12  161.7   1
3   13.885  -14.621 -18.694 -   465.38  161.75  1
4   13.425  -14.674 -18.614 -   465.67  154.52  2
4   13.425  -14.674 -18.614 -   465.67  154.52  2
5   13.153  -14.539 -18.069 -   457.33  136.78  3
5   13.153  -14.539 -18.069 -   457.33  136.78  3
5   13.153  -14.539 -18.069 -   457.33  136.78  3
```

Thank you!

Comment: Actually, in your example, the row which has Frame#5 has been repeated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you share your code and where you are stuck?

Comment: I had tried Excel macros, but it didn't work. So migrated to python. @enke's answer works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pandas, it is very simple. You can pass "Repeat" column to [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv')
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Repeat'])]
```

Output:

```
   Frame#     Yaw   Pitch    Roll KeyCode    EyeX    EyeY  Repeat
0       1  13.116 -13.601 -16.871       -  480.86  175.24       1
1       2  13.553 -14.146 -17.872       -  469.12  161.70       1
2       3  13.885 -14.621 -18.694       -  465.38  161.75       1
3       4  13.425 -14.674 -18.614       -  465.67  154.52       2
3       4  13.425 -14.674 -18.614       -  465.67  154.52       2
4       5  13.153 -14.539 -18.069       -  457.33  136.78       3
4       5  13.153 -14.539 -18.069       -  457.33  136.78       3
4       5  13.153 -14.539 -18.069       -  457.33  136.78       3
```